# How to print N integers using odd and even thread

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to print N numbers from 2 go routines:

**go routine odd():** this can only print odd numbers

**go routine even():** this can only print even numbers

**The output should be:** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

I am trying to solve this problem using sync.WaitGroup. I have following queries:

Q1. Which concurrency mechanism best suited for this problem? channel, waitgroup, mutex, etc? It would be ideal if you could provide a working code for the same.

Q2. Why I am not able to print the sequence correctly through below code? I am doing something wrong which I am not able to rectify. please help in rectifying.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var wgO sync.WaitGroup
var wgE sync.WaitGroup

func even() {
    defer wg.Done()

    for i := 2; i <= 10; i += 2 {
        wgE.Add(1)
        wgO.Wait()
        fmt.Println(i)
        wgE.Done()
    }
}
func odd() {
    defer wg.Done()

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i += 2 {
        wgO.Add(1)
        fmt.Println(i)
        wgO.Done()
        wgE.Wait()
    }
}
func main() {
    wg.Add(2)
    go even()
    go odd()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: not a go pro, but I think those concurrency mechanism you listed are not Independent from another and also not mutually exclusive.  Waitgroup is required to wait until go routines are done. Channels are required to allow communication between go routines and also normal functions. Mutex is there to avoid race conditions if multiple go routines access the same resources.

Comment: The whole _idea_ of concurrency is to be **concurrent**, **independent** streams of execution. Using concurrency to model your problem is **wrong** and you won't learn anything. Basically it is impossible to do what you want: You have to force your goroutines to be **un**concurrent.

Comment: If the output needs to be in order, concurrency is the wrong model.

Comment: @Adrian: What should be used instead for the said problem? Can you please suggest?

Comment: convoluted for convoluted you may have written that https://play.golang.org/p/XYPnLEe0KrW

Comment: It's a good question to understand the limitations of Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: `Which concurrency mechanism best suited for this problem?`

A1: None. Your problem of printing sequential numbers is not a concurrent one. So even if you implemented a solution that uses Go's concurrent mechanisms (either with channels or mutexs), it wouldn't/couldn't actually run concurrently, since what you want is *sequentially* printing your numbers. Running concurrently would print numbers is a non-deterministic order.

Q2: `Why I am not able to print the sequence correctly through below code?`

A2: *Your code prints out of order* because once go routines have been triggered, you have no way of knowing the order in which they are executed. So the code:

```golang
...
go even()
go odd()
...
```

doesn't even guarantee that the loop inside your `even` function will start before the loop inside your `odd` function, even thou the `even` function is called before.

A2.1: *Your code can panic sometimes* `WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned`, because it's possible for `wgO.Done()` inside `odd` function to be called before `wgO.Wait()` is called inside the `even` function.

---

The following is a very **silly** implementation using `sync.WaitGroup` that works, and illustrates how the solution to your problem has to break concurrency to work. In order to print the numbers in order, I have to wait the completion of each go routine...

```golang
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(i int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                fmt.Println(i)
            }(i)
            wg.Wait()
        } else {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(i int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                fmt.Println(i)
            }(i)
            wg.Wait()
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't get too caught up in this problem as it's not a good example for leaning Go's concurrency mechanism.

There is a great course on cooursera for learning Go's concurrency [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/golang-concurrency/home/welcome)

Comment: Thank you @Rafael FT for the detailed explanation. Even though I get so many negative downvotes, I feel this question will still help many other guys who have same misunderstanding of concurrency as mine..and they will understand when to and when not to apply concurrency mechanism :)

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Which concurrency mechanism best suited for this problem? channel, waitgroup, mutex, etc?

None. Your problem is the opposite of something to be done concurrently and no concurrency mechanism helps you.

> Q2. Why I am not able to print the sequence correctly through below code?

You want independent goroutines to run synchronised. So you have to break concurrency. Technically a channel-based ping pong between these two goroutines would work, actually rendering them unconcurrent. Your problem has no sensible "concurrent" solution and you are not going to learn something from a crippled solution where concurrency is forcefully destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement on @Vibhor-Dubey-InfiniteLearner's answer, as there is a deadlock in his answer

```
func odd(n int, syncChannel, done chan bool) {

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        <-syncChannel

        if i%2 != 0 {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }

        syncChannel <- true
    }
    done <- true
}

func even(n int, syncChannel, done chan bool) {

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        <-syncChannel

        if i%2 == 0 {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }

        syncChannel <- true
    }

    done <- true
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    syncChannel := make(chan bool)
    n := 10

    go even(n, syncChannel, done)
    syncChannel <- true // This will ensure, we start at even number
    go odd(n, syncChannel, done)

    <-done
    close(syncChannel)
}
```

Comment: I've added the explanation as a part of answer to your doubt under my response....The approach you're following is a different one.  Again, your approach is different but not incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
    var done int32
    syncChannel := make(chan bool) // unbuffered channel.

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        // prints even numbers.
        defer wg.Done()

        for i := 0; i < 50; i += 2 {
            <-syncChannel

            fmt.Printf("Even: %d\n", i)

            syncChannel <- true
        }
        atomic.StoreInt32(&done, 1)
    }()

    syncChannel <- true

    go func() {
        // prints odd numbers.
        defer wg.Done()

        for i := 1; i < 50; i += 2 {
            <-syncChannel

            fmt.Printf("Odd:%d\n", i)

            if atomic.LoadInt32(&done) != 0 {
                return
            }

            syncChannel <- true
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    close(syncChannel)
}
```

Reference: https://ayada.dev/snippets/ordered-printing-with-goroutines-in-go/

Comment: There is a potential deadlock in this answer. `atomic.LoadInt32(&done) != 0` check can happen before `atomic.StoreInt32(&done, 1)` in the last iteration. In that case it will deadlock at `syncChannel <- true` in odd goroutine

Comment: @SanjeevSiva It will work fine. The condition you're mentioning will never happen as there is a "syncChannel <- true" flag which will execute after our Odd goroutine executes. And it will store value 1......Hope I've answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

We can have odd and even channels.

Each goroutine reads from its corresponding channel and posts to the alternate channel.

The main thread posts the 1 into the odd channel.

After printing N, the goroutine posts to the done channel

The main thread reads the done channel and closes the channels when done.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func printIt(print chan int, next chan int, max int, done chan bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for i := range print {
        fmt.Println(i)
        if i == max {
            done <- true
        } else {
            next <- i + 1
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    N := 10
    oddChan := make(chan int)
    evenChan := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    doneChan := make(chan bool)

    go printIt(oddChan, evenChan, N, doneChan, &wg)
    go printIt(evenChan, oddChan, N, doneChan, &wg)

    oddChan <- 1

    <-doneChan
    close(oddChan)
    close(evenChan)

    wg.Wait()

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to use single channel and two go routines. You can use waitGroup instead of time.sleep but it will print indefinitely.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    initializeEvenOddPrinter()
}

func initializeEvenOddPrinter() {
    channel := make(chan int, 1)
    done := make(chan bool)
    channel <- 0    
    go printEven(channel, &done)
    go printOdd(channel, &done)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(100) * time.Microsecond)
    done <- true
}

func printEven(channel chan int, done *chan bool) {
    for {
        var temp int
        select {
        case temp = <-channel:
            fmt.Println(temp)
            temp++
        case <-*done:
            return
        }
        channel <- temp
    }
}

func printOdd(channel chan int, done *chan bool) {
    for {
        var temp int
        select {
        case temp = <-channel:
            fmt.Println(temp)
            temp++
        case <-*done:
            return
        }
        channel <- temp
    }
}
```